# Remmina : unable to save new connections and passwords

Tags: ssh, remote-desktop, rdp, remmina

Regularly, my Remmina client (installed with snap) doesn't save new connections or new passwords. I can create a new connection, then click on "Save and connect" button, but the connection isn't saved. Same thing for passwords when opening an existing connection and Remmina ask to change the password because the current one is refused. When the situation occurs, I have to completely remove the reinstall Reminna.

When running Remmina in a console, I can see the following log when saving a new connection:

```
** (org.remmina.Remmina:17885): WARNING **: 10:56:45.474: Remmina connection profile cannot be saved, with error 2 (Failed to create file “/home/name/snap/remmina/5070/.local/share/remmina/my_full_connection_name.remmina.PZDBB1”: Permission denied)
```

The mode of `/home/name/snap/remmina/5070/.local/share/remmina` is `drwxr-x---` and the owner is my user `name:name`.

I insist that Remmina works perfectly when I just installed it. The problem occurs after a certain time. I didn't notice a particular situation when the problem starts to occur.

How can I debug this behavior ?

**EDIT:**

Some logs when the error occurs:

```
# /var/log/kern.log
Oct 19 11:23:23 computerName kernel: [10787.678913] audit: type=1400 audit(1634635403.159:346): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="snap.remmina.remmina" name="/home/name/snap/remmina/5070/.local/share/remmina/my_full_connection_name.remmina.PZDBB1" pid=17885 comm="remmina" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
```

```
# /var/log/syslog
Oct 19 11:23:23 computerName kernel: [10787.678913] audit: type=1400 audit(1634635403.159:346): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="snap.remmina.remmina" name="/home/name/snap/remmina/5070/.local/share/remmina/my_full_connection_name.remmina.PZDBB1" pid=17885 comm="remmina" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Oct 19 11:23:23 computerName ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com[2321]: remmina-icon, Impossible to lookup icon for 'org.remmina.Remmina-status-panel' in path /home/name/snap/remmina/5071/.local/share/icons
Oct 19 11:23:23 computerName ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com[2321]: unable to update icon for remmina-icon
```

Comment: Have you seen https://gitlab.com/Remmina/Remmina/-/issues/1404#note_82829331?

Comment: Yes @muru, and Remmina ask to run this command at first start, so it seems not to be the problem here. I edit my question to provide a log.

Comment: Are there are any Remmina-related messages from AppArmor in the system log?

Comment: I edited to add some logs I found.